# On clicking back button in the header an alert should be popped up (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a react native app and I am fairly new to this. I am using React navigation for moving from one page to another.

Currently, I am using a stack navigator. So I have an Screen A which logs in with facebook and then I move to screen B. The header in screen B has a back button. And when I click on it goes back to my facebook login button which now shows log out.

My scenario is if the user clicks on the back button in screen B he should get a pop up in screen b itself. How do I achieve this?

I have the following code in my screen B which is the PhoneInputPage.js

```
 export default class PhoneInputPage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
static navigationOptions = 
{
 title: 'Get started',

 headerStyle:
 {
    position: 'absolute',   
    backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
    zIndex: 100, 
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    right: 0 ,
    justifyContent:'center'
},     
}



render() 
{
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return ( 
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView  style={[styles.container,styles.background]}>
        <Text style={styles.headLine}>Get riding within minutes</Text>
        <View style={styles.container} />
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.input}
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                         keyboardType={'email-address'}
                         autoCorrect={false}
                    />
                </View>
                 <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                     <TextInput
                         placeholder="Phone Number"
                         style={styles.input}
                         underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                         keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                         autoCorrect={false}
                     />


                </View>
                 <Text style={styles.nextText}>We'll send a text to verify your phone</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() =>  navigate('OTP')} underlayColor="transparent">
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>   
        <View style={styles.container} />

    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

  );
```

}
}

I have searched a lot and I couldn't find much help. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.